# failed to execute ['dot', '-Kdot', '-Tsvg'], make sure the Graphviz executables are on your systems' PATH

Tags: python, python-3.x, graphviz

I used this with my decision tree model on my database :

```
dot_data = tree.export_graphviz(pipeline.named_steps['classifier'], out_file=None, 
                         feature_names = categorical_feature_names + numerical_features,
                         class_names=[str(el) for el in pipeline.named_steps.classifier.classes_],  
                         filled=True, rounded=True,  
                         special_characters=True)  
graph = graphviz.Source(dot_data) 
graph
```

And it give me this error :

```
failed to execute ['dot', '-Kdot', '-Tsvg'], make sure the Graphviz executables are on your systems' PATH
```

I read here than I needed it to install it on my notebook to have the proper path : https://github.com/xflr6/graphviz/issues/68

I dit it like that : conda install -c conda-forge python-graphviz

And like that : conda install python-graphviz

Botk worked but None of them resolve the error and I still got her.

Someove have an idea how to resolve this error ?

Thank you.

Comment: You apparently haven't installed GraphViz yet.  `python-graphviz` is just a Python module for talking to the application, it's not the application itself.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add graphviz executable to your PATH. Is not a matter to install the module with conda or pip. This is my solution working with a Mac:

1. Open a terminal and enter `vim .zshrc` (I use zsh)
2. Insert `export PATH="/usr/local/opt/graphviz/bin:$PATH"`
3. Save and quit (:wq)

This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

For me, on Windows plus Visual Studio, downloading and installing this [graphviz](https://graphviz.org/download/) got everything to start working.