# GRAPHVIZ: failed to execute ['dot', '-Kdot', '-Tsvg'], make sure the Graphviz executables are on your systems' PATH

Tags: python, macos, path, graphviz

I am new to this and I am trying to plot a Decision Tree in my Jupiter notebook in Jupiter lab using Graphviz - on MacOS.

#### Code

```
def draw_tree(t, col_names, size=9, ratio=0.5, precision=3):
""" Draws a representation of a random forest in IPython.
Parameters:
-----------
t: The tree you wish to draw
df: The data used to train the tree. This is used to get the names of the features.
"""
s=export_graphviz(t, out_file=None, feature_names=col_names, filled=True,
                  special_characters=True, rotate=True, precision=precision)
IPython.display.display(graphviz.Source(re.sub('Tree {',
   f'Tree {{ size={size}; ratio={ratio}',s)))
```

`draw_tree(dt, cols_to_keep, precision=3)`

#### Issue

But I got following `FileNotFoundError`:

```
FileNotFoundError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
    ~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/graphviz/backend.py in run(cmd, input, capture_output, check, encoding, quiet, **kwargs)
        163     try:
    --> 164         proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd, startupinfo=get_startupinfo(), **kwargs)
        165     except OSError as e:
    
    ~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py in __init__(self, args, bufsize, executable, stdin, stdout, stderr, preexec_fn, close_fds, shell, cwd, env, universal_newlines, startupinfo, creationflags, restore_signals, start_new_session, pass_fds, encoding, errors, text)
        853 
    --> 854             self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
        855                                 pass_fds, cwd, env,
    
    ~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py in _execute_child(self, args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds, pass_fds, cwd, env, startupinfo, creationflags, shell, p2cread, p2cwrite, c2pread, c2pwrite, errread, errwrite, restore_signals, start_new_session)
       1701                         err_msg = os.strerror(errno_num)
    -> 1702                     raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg, err_filename)
       1703                 raise child_exception_type(err_msg)
    
    FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'dot'
    
    During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
    
    ExecutableNotFound                        Traceback (most recent call last)
    ~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/IPython/core/formatters.py in __call__(self, obj)
        343             method = get_real_method(obj, self.print_method)
        344             if method is not None:
    --> 345                 return method()
        346             return None
        347         else:
    
    ~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/graphviz/files.py in _repr_svg_(self)
        142 
        143     def _repr_svg_(self):
    --> 144         return self.pipe(format='svg').decode(self._encoding)
        145 
        146     def pipe(self, format=None, renderer=None, formatter=None, quiet=False):
    
    ~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/graphviz/files.py in pipe(self, format, renderer, formatter, quiet)
        167         data = text_type(self.source).encode(self._encoding)
        168 
    --> 169         out = backend.pipe(self._engine, format, data,
        170                            renderer=renderer, formatter=formatter,
        171                            quiet=quiet)
    
    ~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/graphviz/backend.py in pipe(engine, format, data, renderer, formatter, quiet)
        246     """
        247     cmd, _ = command(engine, format, None, renderer, formatter)
    --> 248     out, _ = run(cmd, input=data, capture_output=True, check=True, quiet=quiet)
        249     return out
        250 
    
    ~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/graphviz/backend.py in run(cmd, input, capture_output, check, encoding, quiet, **kwargs)
        165     except OSError as e:
        166         if e.errno == errno.ENOENT:
    --> 167             raise ExecutableNotFound(cmd)
        168         else:
        169             raise
    
    ExecutableNotFound: failed to execute ['dot', '-Kdot', '-Tsvg'], make sure the Graphviz executables are on your systems' PATH

sys.version
'3.8.3 (default, Jul  2 2020, 11:26:31) \
```

#### What I tried

I have tried to reinstalled the `graphviz` python-module:

```
!pip install graphviz
```

But it was still there:

> Requirement already satisfied: graphviz in
> /Users/jessycebrian/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages (0.16)

Furthermore, I found and tried this answer:

- [failed to execute ['dot', '-Kdot', '-Tsvg'], make sure the Graphviz executables are on your systems' PATH](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65779190/failed-to-execute-dot-kdot-tsvg-make-sure-the-graphviz-executables)

What else can I do to be able to plot it?

Comment: Try 'brew install graphviz' first. Pip module is not an executable itself, it's just a "connector". If you have it installed, check whether graphviz executable is in PATH.